# Notification mail in open atrium

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

I have a problem on how to send mail on notification while editing or creating any contents in open atrium.

I have followed as mentioned in below link
https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/28

but was not successful in sending mail to notified user on creating or editing of contents.

And also i wanted to send a mail to user when his credentials is changed or edited.

May can anyone help me in rectifying this issues.

Answer (score 2):

Is your server/PHP enabled to send mails?

Maybe that is not the case and this is why no messages are sent.

In any way you can do a couple of tests to check that out what is wrong. For some, you will need the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) installed:

- Check if your server has the SMTP functionality installed and running (how to check this changes a lot from server to server)
- Check if your PHP installation manages to send mail. There are plenty of available scripts to do this on the internet. I C&P one below.
- Check if you can send mails with drupal (with the develop module installed, visit `http://example.com/devel/php` and use the [`drupal_mail()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_mail) function.
- Change the setting from the devel module and put the mail to "log only": this will show you if Open Atrium is at least *trying* to send them.

Example PHP script to test mail functionality.

```
$to = "recipient@example.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} 
else {
  echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
?>
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OpenAtrium Installation docs](https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/30), all you need to do is enable the [standard Drupal cron job]. That worked for me in my OpenAtrium installation. Just to be clear, I did not have to alter php.ini or install the Drupal SMTP module.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is not realistic. Take a look to this post:
https://community.openatrium.com/issues/node/79

Fixed installing smtp module and letting openatrium mail with PHPMailer.